# phonegap Geolocation without WiFi and mobile network

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, gps

I am developing an application using Phonegap for Android and use its geolocation method. This only works when mobile network or WiFi are available. I would like to use geolocation without these being available. Is this possible?

Comment: have you turned on location in phone settings?

Comment: ok. Did you request the proper location permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: yes.I have done all things listed in the Phonegap site(Phonegap document).Is WiFi must be switched on?

Comment: Phonegap will automatically take the best location provider. If Wifi is better when location is requested, it'll use that instead of GPS.

Comment: Thank you, I thought Phonegap works only with WiFi or mobile network.It may be a problem with my location And GPS is not available here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Android to use the GPS receiver on the device, you need to set the "enableHighAccuracy" option when setting up the watcher in you Phonegap app:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Then you will be able to obtain a location without relying on Wifi or mobile network.

Comment: How exactly is it failing? What android device are you using? Did you add the correct permissions to the manifest and config XML files?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> these permissions am using in xml file. And it is not giving location at all. It goes to onError function

Comment: did you add location functionality to the phonegap config? e.g. `<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>` What error code and error message is being passed to the onError function?

Comment: So what error code and error message are you getting in onError? And what version of Phonegap?

Comment: cordova 2.5.0 version

Comment: That version should be fine. what error code and error message are you getting? And what Android device are you testing it on?

Comment: error is as follows : Error retrieving location information: [object PositionError]

Comment: You need to log the contents of the PositionError object - it contains both a code and a message ([see here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#PositionError)) - these will tell you the actual error that's occurring. Maybe best to ask this as a new question and post all the relevant details.

Comment: PERMISSION_DENIED 1
 
POSITION_UNAVAILABLE 2
 
TIMEOUT 3

Comment: I asked new question :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507780/how-to-get-the-geolocation-in-phonegap-without-internet

Answer (score -1):

You can not get the location of your device without a data connection (mobile network and/or Wifi). If you DO have a data connection and you have the proper location permission in your manifest file, you will get the geolocation. Am I understanding the question correctly?