# How to get the geolocation in phonegap without internet?

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

I am using phonegap to develop android app for mobile.
I am using following code  :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error,{enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout: 30000,maximumAge: 30000});
```

still it tells can't give gps . It gives position error without internet .
If internet is their then it gives proper lonlat.

Without internet how i should make this work??
Is it possible only from phonegap itself??

I am getting error code 3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by writing phonegap native plugin for android . I referred location manager in java , which works without internet .